# Get Random Set of Entries

Tags: templating

I'm trying to create a "Hack Job" version of Similar Entries, I'm using the following code but it seems to be getting the same entries over and over again. I know shuffle function does this, but I thought it'd be shuffling through the entire array of Entries?

```
{% set nextEntries = shuffle(craft.entries.section('merchants').id('not ' ~ entry.id).limit(15)) %}
```

I'm looking to make it grab a random 15 entries from the `merchants` section, which I will then cache.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always getting the same set because the entries are first fetched, then shuffled. To achieve what you want, you could do:

```twig
{# get all your entries ids #}
{% set allIds = craft.entries().section('yourSection').ids() %}
{# Shuffle all and slice to just 15 #}
{% set shuffledIds = shuffle(allIds) | slice(0,15) %}
{# Fetch your random entries #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.id(shuffledIds).all() %}
```

Or

```twig
{# get all your entries ids #}
{% set allIds = craft.entries().section('yourSection').ids() %}
{# Fetch your random entries #}
{% set entries = craft.entries().id(shuffle(allIds) | slice(0,15)).all() %}
```

In response to your comment then you could do something like the below:

```twig
{# set a random offset #}
{% set offset = random(0, 6000)%}

{# set a random sort #}
{% set orderBy = random(['postDate', 'id', 'title']) %}

{# set a random direction #}
{% set direction = random(['ASC', 'DESC']) %}

{# get 500 ids #}
{% set allIds = craft
            .entries()
            .section('posts')
            .offset(offset)
            .orderBy(orderBy ~ ' ' ~ direction)
            .limit(500)
            .ids() %}

{# Fetch your random entries #}
{% set entries = craft.entries().id(shuffle(allIds) | slice(0,15)).all() %}
```

With this, you only fetch 500 entries with a random offset and sorting, shuffle that pool and pick 15. This might not be *as* random but I doubt you'd notice it.

Comment: Due to it being a fairly large site with over 8k entries. Would this cause strain to fetch this many ID's?

Comment: @JMKelley just added another option for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the orberBy('RAND()') function. I learned this one just the other day. (It might only be for Craft CMS 4)

```
{% set nextEntries = craft.entries.section('merchants').id('not ' ~ entry.id).limit(15).orderBy('RAND()') %}
```